# Issue calling database trigger with long process in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to read a huge directory and its subdirectories and files ,then write to database.Everything is fine but i put a trigger on a table that it is fired when a data is inserted and update another table.Trigger works fine with a single sql command but

Due to long process in the main program , trigger is not fired. I am using queue dequeue , and backroundworker thread.(c#)

How can this problem be solved.?any idea apreciated.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? why would the trigger not be fired if the first process is long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the trigger is working OK, but you need all the data to be processed before seeing the trigger effects take place. Therefore, I suggest that you split the data into smaller pieces (batches), and insert them to the database one by one. Basically, choose a size of the batch that suits best your setup and load the data on iterations.

Here is some example C# code:

```
public void ProcessData(String rootDirectory, int batchSize) 
{
    IEnumerable<string> pathsToProcess = GetPathsToProcess(rootDirectory);

    int currentBatch = 0;
    while (currentBatch*batchSize < pathsToProcess.Length) 
    {
        // take a subset of the paths to process
        IEnumerable<string> batch = pathsToProcess
            .Skip(currentBatch*batchSize)
            .Take(batchSize);

        DoYourDatabaseLogic(batch);

        currentBatch++;
    }
}
```

The code above will execute the database operation for a smaller subset of data, after which your trigger will execute against that data. This will happen for each of the batches. You will still have to wait for all the batches to complete, but you can see the changes for the ones that have completed.

Using this approach brings, however, an important issue to worry about: **What would happen if some of the batches fails for some reason?**

- In case you must revert all the changes for the entire `pathsToProcess` collection if a single batch/subset of it fails, you should organize the above code **to run in a single database transaction**, and ensure the rollback takes place appropriately.
- If the `pathsToProcess` collection is not required to be rolled back entirely, I still recommend using transactions on each of the batches. In that case you may need to know which batch did you write last successfully, in order to resume from it if the data is to get processed again.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out if I love or hate the use of linq here :)

Comment: @Noctis, do you see something wrong in particular that I may be missing? I'd be glad to fix it

Comment: Not at all. It is elegant, and seems correct. Usually I'd solve it with an int variable and just multiply it by the counter. Linq brings both simplicity and complexity to this answer at the same time.

Comment: @Noctis, thanks. I agree, this will reduce the boilerplate of writing the multiplication each time :). I have left it this way as a potential hint to the OP, so that s/he can use the `currentBatch` index if s/he needs to keep track of the batch progress, or to use it in case of resuming the processing on failure (I just added to the answer so you may have missed that part by the time of commenting)